# Questioning Company Project Structure

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, capacitor

I recently got a new job and am quite new to the React JS developer scene and have gotten to work understanding and working with the companies codebase.

Currently with have three repos:

1. Main Website ( React JS )
2. Mobile Application ( React JS and Capacitor )
3. Design System ( Basically its storybook that stores all the components )

Now here is the part I am having a hard time understanding. There was a decision to not only share the components through the design-system but to also share business logic.

In this case the design-system doesn't only house components, It also contains our **Redux Store** (Including its logic). We then link our Design System to our other projects (Website and mobile) pulling  all the components and Redux as needed. I have searched to find examples of such a setup throughout the internet but I haven't found any examples.

My question is, Is it a practice to store your redux store and its logic within another repository? outside of the actual react project?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a common practice. As long as you can abstract code it's in most cases a good idea to do so.

Redux additionally supports modularization very well and can be well-used for such a use case.

Now in your case the design system isn't just a design system any more. It's a library that's used as an abstraction layer for your business needs.

Comment: That's interesting, I will take a look at this Redux modularization